# Would keeping someone at home under fear of violence be abduction under Indian Penal Code section 364A?

Tags: criminal-law, india, indian-penal-code, kidnapping

[IPC 364A](https://www.indiacode.nic.in/show-data?actid=AC_CEN_5_23_00037_186045_1523266765688&sectionId=46137&sectionno=364A&orderno=410) states

> Whoever kidnaps or abducts any person or keeps a person in detention after such kidnapping or abduction, and threatens to cause death or hurt to such person, or by his conduct gives rise to a reasonable apprehension that such person may be put to death or hurt, or causes hurt or death to such person in order to compel the Government or any foreign State or international inter-governmental organisation or any other person to do or abstain from doing any act or to pay a ransom, shall be punishable with death or imprisonment for life, and shall also be liable to fine.

abduction is defined as

> Whoever by force compels, or by any deceitful means induces any person to go from any place, is said to abduct that person.

The example :

> A person who had severe stress harassed his mother so that she could give him money to see a psychiatrist, he even forced her to stay at home and not go anywhere and the likes because he didn't want to be alone. He threatened to hurt his mom on a call with his friends with the intention so they gave him money, he used knives and scissors to harm himself as well while his mother tried to stop him. he even tried to seek help internationally for his stress because he didn't trust local helplines. or to get some international  organization to help them

Answer (score 2):

This is unlikely to be abduction, because he:

> forced her ***to stay at home and not go anywhere***

Which does not meet the definition at [section 362](https://www.indiacode.nic.in/show-data?actid=AC_CEN_5_23_00037_186045_1523266765688&sectionId=46133&sectionno=362&orderno=406):

> Whoever by force compels, or by any deceitful means induces, any person ***to go from*** any place, is said to abduct that person.

The offence would seem to be extortion, contrary to [section 383](https://www.indiacode.nic.in/show-data?actid=AC_CEN_5_23_00037_186045_1523266765688&sectionId=46166&sectionno=383&orderno=440) IPC:

> Whoever intentionally puts any person in fear of any injury to that person, or to any other, and thereby dishonestly induces the person so put in fear to deliver to any person any property, or valuable security or anything signed or sealed which may be converted into a valuable security, commits "extortion".

The punishments for extortion depends on the circumstances (and evidence) may be found at sections 384 to 389.

Also, consider this *could* be robbery contrary to the second paragraph of [section 390](https://www.indiacode.nic.in/show-data?actid=AC_CEN_5_23_00037_186045_1523266765688&orderno=447) IPC:

> In all robbery there is either theft or extortion.
>
> **When theft is robbery**.—Theft is "robbery" if, in order to the committing of the theft, or in committing the theft, or in carrying away or attempting to carry away property obtained by the theft, the offender, for that end voluntarily causes or attempts to cause to any person death or hurt or wrongful restraint, or fear of instant death or of instant hurt, or of instant wrongful restraint.
>
> **When extortion is robbery**.—Extortion is "robbery" if the offender, at the time of committing the extortion, is in the presence of the person put in fear, and commits the extortion by putting that person in fear of instant death, of instant hurt, or of instant wrongful restraint to that person or to some other person, and, by so putting in fear, induces the person so put in fear then and there to deliver up the thing extorted.

The punishment for which may be found at sections 392 to 294, 397 and 398.

Comment: could it be possible that this doesn't amount to roberry either ?

Comment: @IndianLawDropout It could amount robbery by extortion if the elements of the second part of s.390 are met

Comment: what I meant was are there any possible circumstances that could put this out of section 390 even if it is a textbook case of this ?

Comment: @IndianLawDropout Only if the all the elements aren't met such as not being *in the presence of the person put in fear*. The UK police exams have a similar question where the offender is using WhatsApp to remotely threaten the victim to transfer money over the Internet. This is not robbery (under UK law) but is blackmail (which is similar to India's extortion offence). Hope this helps.

Comment: @Rick if I'm not wrong this is the lex specialis principle right ? is it neccesary to apply it ?

Comment: @IndianLawDropout It *might* apply, but that's a separate question - let's concentrate on one at a time :)

Comment: I undestand but well this question is particularly relevant because I know a case in the example that happened irl

Comment: @Rick isn't the whole answer basically an example of lex specialis ? what do you mean by "it might apply" the answer states that it clearly does.